# Symfony 3 Virtual Hosts, can't make it to /web

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, symfony

I'm trying to setup the Symfony 3 on my local server and the problem is I can't make my Virtual Hosts working.

vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost.dev.lt
    ServerAlias www.localhost.dev.lt

    DocumentRoot /www/testProject/web
    <Directory /www/testProject/web/>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
    #<Directory /www/testProject/>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    #</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I added localhost.dev.lt into my hosts file.
Mod Rewrite module is also enabled.

Could the DocumentRoot URL be written wrong? 
If I go to http://localhost.dev.lt/testProject/web/
Then it's working, the problem is that I get root directory then I go to http://localhost.dev.lt instead of /web.

Comment: You should define better what you mean by "it's working" or "it's not working". Exactly what do you see on the page in each of those cases?

Comment: This is not the proper configuration. Either you should be directing your traffic to app(_dev).php, or use `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, the problem was that the vhosts.conf file was commented in main httpd.conf file, so the virtual hosts was not working at all. The line was "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf".

Answer (score 1):

If navigating to `http://localhost.dev.lt/testProject/web/` shows the home page of your Symfony project, make sure you don't have a **different** virtual host that sets `localhost.dev.lt` to `/www/`.